# Having Problem with Importing Excel file to Mathematica Notebook?

Tags: matrix, import, excel

I have solved some equations and exported the final results, which they are several Matrices, as a EXCEL file ( .Xls ). Now, I want to use these EXCEL files as my inputs to solve some other equations. I use `Import[]` to read these EXCEL files. But when I import them, these Matrices appears like this : 
`{"ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]"}`

When I use `Import[exp,"Table"]` or `Import[exp,"List"]` the results are exactly same as previous one.

I don't know what the problem is ?!

This is part of the code :

```
AA = Import["C:\\Users\\Com\\Desktop\\EXCEL\\AA.Xls", "List"];

BB = Import["C:\\Users\\Com\\Desktop\\EXCEL\\BB.Xls", "List"];

CC = Import["C:\\Users\\Com\\Desktop\\EXCEL\\CC.Xls", "List"];

ssm = StateSpaceModel[{AA, BB, CC}]
```

The results :

> ```
> During evaluation of In[8]:= StateSpaceModel::farg: {{ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]},
> {ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]},{ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]}} is not a valid TransferFunctionModel
> or a list of state-space matrices in the form {a, b, ...}. >>`
>
> During evaluation of In[8]:= StateSpaceModel::farg: {{ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]},
> {ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]},{ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]}} is not a valid TransferFunctionModel 
> or a list of state-space matrices in the form {a, b, ...}. >>
>
> StateSpaceModel[{{"ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]"}, {"ÐÏ\.11à¡\\[PlusMinus]"}, 
> {"ÐÏ\.11à¡\[PlusMinus]"}}]`
> ```

Comment: any chance you can upload the file (or a section of it)? Also make sure you're not switching between 32 and 64 bit applications.

Comment: @ Jonie : Sorry! It's not possible for me to upload it! But if you want, I can write here part of the code which I have faced problem with!?

Comment: @ Jonie : I edited my question and added codes.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are storing your mathematica results in Excel files? Have you tried repeating this by saving your work to other formats?

Comment: What does the data look like in the Excel file? Does it show up correctly? Maybe the file is already corrupted upon export. Could you post the code you are using for exporting?

Comment: @  Mike Honeychurch : In fact, No! Because they're Matrices, I thought that EXCEL file would be great for saving results! Do you have any idea?

Comment: @  Alexander Schmitz : I have checked Excel files with my results. They are the same. But when I import the Excel files in Mthematica, Mathematica change my matrices. I mean it seems like you use ` Transpose[]` first then import my matrices!! That's weird !!

Comment: @Shield if you like using Excel to view large matrices, try getting used to using `TableForm` and `Take` or `Part` to view your matrices inside _Mathematica_. Furthermore, note that adding a second argument to `Import` like "List" or "Table" should not be necessary in this case. To save your matrices to the hard disk, see `DumpSave` and `Save`, or try directly to `Export` to the formats .mx .m. `Dumpsave` and `Export` to .mx create computer dependent versions. File created by Save and .m files can shared between computers.

Comment: I have tested things and it seems indeed using "List" or "Table" causes the trouble. Just use `matrix = First@Import[fileName];`

Comment: More evidence that you are not supposed to use "List" or "Table" here comes from `Import[filePath, "Elements"]`. This shows you all the valid strings that can be used as second arguments. Here I think "Data" is the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not `Import[]` the matrices back in *Mathematica* using the options *"List"* or *"Table"*, because that causes the problem. The solution is to use `Import["file.xls", "Data"][[1]]` or just omit the *"Data"* option `Import["file.xls"][[1]]`. You can also use Mathlink for Excel, if you have one, to copy and paste data between the two applications.

Comment: @ Nikola Dimitrov : Thank you Nikola !! That's the best way!!

Comment: Glad to help :)